# Chaining observables Angular 5 / Rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, angular5, ecmascript-2016

I am a bit confused with rxjs operators. I have few api calls that return observable:

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(userUrl);
  }

tagsList(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>(tagsUrl);
  }

timezonesList(): Observable<Timezone[]> {
    return this.http.get<Timezone[]>(timezonesUrl);
  }
```

I want to call `getCurrentUser()` then with result of returning value call action `LoadUser(user)`
Then after user loads call multiple async requests at the same time:

```
tagsList(), timezonesList()
```

And then with results of returning value of them call actions `LoadTags(tags), LoadTimezones(timezones)`

So it should looks like something like this:

```
init() {
  this.accountsApi.getCurrentUser()
      .map((user: User) => this.store.dispatch(new LoadUser({ user })))
      .map(
        this.commonApi.tagsList(),
        this.commonApi.timezonesList(),
        this.commonApi.authoriztionServicesList()
      )
      .map((tags, timezones, authorizationServices) => {
        this.store.dispatch(new tagsActions.LoadTags(tags));
        this.store.dispatch(new timezonesActions.LoadTimezones(timezones));
        this.store.dispatch(new authorizationServicesActions.LoadAuthorizationServices(authorizationServices));
      });
}
```

I know that this operators are wrong. What operators should i use for this? I have already done it with promises, but i am sure that i can do it with rxjs operators in less line of code.

P.S. Also it is interesting for me how i can do this with async / await? Thank you

Comment: What's should the return type of `init()` be?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Actually, `return` is unnecessary. I updated question and remove `return`

Answer (score 0):

In your original code you are using map a bit too much, for some use cases you may not need to map.

```
init() {
  return this.accountsApi.getCurrentUser()
      .do((user: User) => this.store.dispatch(new LoadUser({ user })))
      .forkJoin(
        this.commonApi.tagsList(),
        this.commonApi.timezonesList(),
        this.commonApi.authoriztionServicesList()
      )
      .do((results) => {
        this.store.dispatch(new tagsActions.LoadTags(results[0]));
        this.store.dispatch(new timezonesActions.LoadTimezones(results[1]));
        this.store.dispatch(new authorizationServicesActions.LoadAuthorizationServices(results[2]));
      });
}
```

**forkJoin** lets you fire off many observable subscriptions and once all subscriptions produce values you get a single array of observable values back.

The **do** operator introduces side effects to launch your store actions since you don't want to create any arrays.

Comment: Thanks you, i know about too much maps, i wrote it is just as an example, because i don't know what operators should i use there. But is it possible to make it without array[index]?
Handle it somehow with interfaces of returning values of commonApi's calls? Like i wrote in my last code example